# Shoutem Builder crash: Which Shoutem extensions are absolutely required?

Tags: shoutem

The app I'm developing using Shoutem doesn't require user login credentials, so I decided to remove the 'Users' extension from my Shoutem project. After doing this and rebuilding the app in the Shoutem Builder preview window, 
[I get this error when the builder app preview launches.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ydyvh.jpg) It works just fine when I re-add the Users extension in builder. I do not have any 'Users' screens in my app project.

I was planning on using Builder to remove the extensions I don't need, but it seems like removing the 'Users' extension broke the app, even though I'm not using the extension's functionality.

Aside from 'Users', which extensions are required to be left in all Shoutem Builder-created projects, regardless of functionality, in order to not break the app?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Certain extensions depend on other extensions. Uninstalling the basic extensions (installed with every new app created) can cause issues on the Builder. Uninstalling is intended as a feature for developers working hands-on with the code.

Uninstalling extensions should be done with care and tested locally to have access to the full error log.
We have [documentation](https://shoutem.github.io/docs/extensions/tutorials/setting-local-environment) available that guides you through setting up your local environment.

**NOTE:** After uninstalling an extension, you will have to re-clone the app in order to receive an up-to-date representation of your app. Alternatively, you can manually remove the extension you uninstalled from your locally cloned app.